# Variable declaration not properly checked by compiler

Tags: c

When declaring a variable or pointer, the compiler assumes the variable or pointer itself is already declared when being assigned as a value during declaration.

I have tried both gcc and clang and they compile the "faulty" code without complaining.

CASE 1: This will not compile since "a" is not declared:

```
void main()
{
int b=sizeof(a);
}
```

CASE 2: This compiles without a problem:

```
void main()
{
int a=sizeof(a);
}
```

Shouldn't the compiler generate the "a is undeclared" error instead, just like in case 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Shouldn't the compiler generate the "a is undeclared" error instead, just like in case 1?

Why? It just saw you declare `a`.

```
int a = sizeof(a);
 // ^--- here it is, before its first use
```

The declaration of a variable begins after its declarator is seen, right before its (optional) initializer. So you can even write the truly faulty

```
int a = a;
```

Note however that in your case there is nothing faulty being done. The result of `sizeof` depends only on the *type* of `a`, and the type is known. This is a well defined initializtion (with a conversion from `size_t` to `int`, but not one to be worried about).

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation. I was assuming declaration won't take place if the initializer was invalid, but now I understand how it works.

Comment: @BernaldoHills - Glad I could be of help!

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` is not a function depending on the value of `a`; it is a builtin that is evaluated at compile time, so it becomes equivalent to

```
int a = 4;
```